# SKU validation with jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm trying to make a validation SKU of this product, showing an alert message. Before, I had the same problem in another situation.

```php
<?php foreach($dvdLists as $key => $dvdList) { ?>   
    <p class="sku-validator-dvd" style="visibility:hidden;"><?= $dvdList->sku ?></p>
<?php } ?>
```

I tried to do the same solution with each function but doesn't work. I need to get each SKU product to make a comparison with the SKU input. Doing this that way I can only get the first one. The second forward doesn't work.

```js
$('#save_product').click(function(e){
    var skuInput = $.trim($('#sku').val());
    if(skuInput  ===  $('.sku-validator-dvd').text()) {
        alert('This sku already exists');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#save_product').click(function(e){
    var skuInput = $.trim($('#sku').val());
    var skuExists = false;
    $('.sku-validator-dvd').each(function() {
        if (skuInput === $(this).text()) {
            skuExists = true;
        }
    });
    if (skuExists) {
        alert('This sku already exists');
    }
});
```

Try this

Comment: I got the same problem. I can get only the first one. When I have 2 DVD products, the alert message doesn't work.